# Merge only the last commit from a branch into master

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

I made a test repository using the below commands

```
mkdir test-repo
cd test-repo/
git init
```

I made a file in the directory and committed the changes

```
echo 0 > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m '0'
```

I made a new branch for development

```
git checkout -b A
```

The file is changed now in branch A, added '1' in the next line

```
file.txt
0
1
```

committed to branch A

```
git add file.txt
git commit -m '1'
```

Added an empty new file file1.txt in 'A'. Then committed

```
git add file1.txt
git commit -m 'new file'
```

Now the reflog command shows as

```
76633b7 (HEAD -> A) HEAD@{0}: commit: new file
070f015 HEAD@{1}: commit: 1
dfab60f (master) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to A
dfab60f (master) HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): 0
```

Now i want to merge branch A to master with only the commit with '76633b7'(last one). I dont want the 'commit:1'(070f015) in the master. How can i do this?. git merge A will commit all the changes to the master.

Comment: Do you want everything in master except 76633b7 ? or you want only 76633b7 in master. in second case "git cherry-pick 76633b7 " from master will work.

Comment: yeah that worked... I tried..

Comment: I have added answer with second scenario as well. You might want to take a look :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two scenarios.

1) You want to merge only last commit (76633b7) to master.
   - In that case , just do following

```
 i)  git checkout master
 ii) git cherry-pick 76633b7
```

2) You want everything from branch A in master except second last commit.
   - This is little tricky, you have to do following in that case

```
 i) Change the order of last and second last commit


  git rebase -i HEAD~2

  Next, change the order of the commits in the prompt.

  pick 76633b7 
  pick 070f015

  to 

  pick 070f015
  pick 76633b7
```

Now your second commit is on top and everything else you want to merge is below second commit.

ii) Now you can simply merge using commit id of your old first commit (which is second now )

```
git merge 76633b7
```

Answer (score 4):

You could provide the id of the revision to cherry-pick (as has been said) but if you ask to cherry-pick *a branch*  only the last revision will be cherry-picked so this will work as well:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick A
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward solution for that. Your commit `76633b7` rests upon commit `070f015` and might theoretically depend on what you have done there.

What you can do:

```
git checkout -b B master # create a new branch B from master
git cherry-pick 76633b7 # apply the commit 76633b7 and resolve conflicts if any
```

now the B branch contains only the commit that you want to merge into master.

Comment: @JaangoJayaraj in that case, please accept this answer so other people can see this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In order to merge latest commit from another branch you can use cherry pick followed by the branch name you want to pick the latest commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_examples
Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit with this change.

```
git checkout develop // the branch you want to merge commit into
git cherry-pick master // the branch you want to get commit from
```

I was trying to use `git cherry-pick commitid` but that way I was getting error: `commit commitid is a merge but no -m option was given.` However by using a branch name with cherry-pick I was able to succesfully merge the latest commit into a branch.