# Merge only the last commit

Tags: git, github

I'm a beginner with GIT and I'm trying to implement as followed :
[image: Ideal Workflow]

To explain that, I want to implement each feature to have a it's own branch and when it is over and the feature is working how I want (here B.3) I simply want to clone the B.3 into a new main commit (which is C in the picture). Then B.3 = C

I believe that If I do a **git merge**, B1, B2 and B3 would be cloned into main. But I don't want the history of the feature in the main branch, I just want the last one in order to get a main branch clean which evolve feature after feature.

PS: Since I work alone in the dev projects, I don't need other specific branch or else. :)

Is it even possible? (I believe so after discovering the power of git !)

Thanks! :)

Comment: B.3 contains B.2 plus some modifications and B.2 contains B.1 plus some modifications right?

Comment: Yes exactly ! It is just the evolution and tests of the feature. B.3 is the final state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge only the last commit from a branch into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039980/merge-only-the-last-commit-from-a-branch-into-master)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about cherry picking. I'm a bit confused now.  What is the difference between cherry picking the last commit of a branch and merge the branch ? If I merge the branch, will I have 3 new commits in my main or just one ? I just want as less commit as possible in the main branch :/

Comment: You've worded the question in a conflicting way IMO.  To me it sounds like you want the *contents* of commit B.1, B.2, and B.3, from your branch to look as *one commit* on your main branch.  You're looking for a [squash](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-squash/).  You take several commits and "replay" them into a single commit, with a commit message that generally describes the entirety of the squashed commit.  You lose the "history" of how things evolved in the branch you squashed to, so it looks like a single commit.

Comment: In short, merge carries forward everything, cherry-pick is what the name says , i.e. pick what you wish. Merge alone is something you don't want as per your current requirement.

Comment: Since you have just started out on your git journey, I would like to point you to few very useful resources : [Atlassian-Git-Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-git), [Learn Git Branching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/), [GitHub's Git Resources](https://try.github.io/). and lastly [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972713/2915738) which answers the merge vs cherry-pick, and [another one from same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53974633/2915738), but I believe this last post will be a bit heavy considering you have just started out learning git.

Answer (score 1):

On a Github pull request you can use the [Squash and Merge](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits) button